Add default route on physical interface using `systemd-networkd`
In /lib/systemd/network/10-eth0.network on my client, I am failing to configure anything that can translate my manual command:
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.7.1 dev eth0

where 192.168.7.1 is the static IPv4 address of my host.
My last 10-eth0.network configuration attempt:
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Route]
Address=192.168.7.2/24
Destination=192.168.7.1/32
Gateway=192.168.7.1

Refreshed with sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd and validated with ip route (it doesn't show up).
See also:

[Route] Section Options
Answers that aren't working: systemd-networkd and direct routes


If 7.1 is the address of your host, 1) why are you specifying it as the gateway, and 2) what's 7.2 supposed to be then? Do you mean that 7.1 is the address of the router and 7.2 is the host with systemd?

192.168.7.1 is arbitrary host Ethernet port to client's 192.168.7.2 Ethernet port. 192.168.7.1 is not a router per se. Router is in another subnet block, e.g. 10.0.0.1.

Okay, so .7.2 is the host being configured and .7.1 is another host. Is 192.168.7.1 acting as a router, at least?

192.168.7.1 is an Ethernet interface of machine that is supposed to forward traffic via its WAN interface for the 192.168.7.2 'edge'/'client' device.

You didn't specify anywhere that it's supposed to be the default route; instead you have Destination=192.168.7.1/32 – which is the complete opposite of a default route... as well as being a cyclical (self-referencing) route. According to your configuration, it probably shows up as a 192.168.7.1/32 dev eth0 in your route output (that would be the effective interpretation assuming the kernel doesn't reject it).
The default route is always 0.0.0.0/0, i.e. a lowest-precedence catch-all route, and that's what you need to define as the Destination=. (Alternatively you can omit Destination= entirely.)
A route via Gateway=192.168.7.1 can only be defined if you are in the same subnet. For that, make sure that the Address=192.168.7.2 parameter is either in an [Address] section or in the [Network] section – it makes no sense in the [Route] section.

If it performs IP forwarding, it is a gateway by definition.

Adding Gateway=192.168.7.1 in the [Network] section works.
